# Segmentation Fault while using Static Linking using C++ Threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, static-linking

I am using the following code snippet and compiling using the static linking.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <thread>

void hello()
{
    std::cout<<"Hello Concurrent World\n";
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t(hello);
    t.join();
}
```

Here is the compilation command which I am using -

```
g++ -std=c++11 -o main -pthread  -static -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ temp.cpp
```

but when I try to execute the generated binary, I am getting segmentation fault.

But I dont see any error If I compile using the following command -

```
g++ -std=c++11 -o main2 -pthread  temp.cpp
```

Can someone please help what might be causing the segmentation fault while compiling using the static linking.

Comment: It works fine with g++ 11.2.1.on Fedora 35

Comment: ... and with the answer @RichardCritten linked too, it works in [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/KhPzoqc9P) too